# Can't find .lib file MSVC++ 2008

Tags: c, visual-c++

I am compiling my project with msvc++ 2008. I have added a reference path in project properties to ./lib, which is the directory that contains the file freeglut.lib. I have been very careful to organize everything nicely, and still msvc++ does not find the file :(. I checked the build log, to see that no where in the build command line does it say ./lib. Might this be the issue? I've included the build log, in hopes that someone can help to solve this. Thanks in advance

```
`Build Log
```

Rebuild started: Project: triangle_wars, Configuration: Debug|Win32

Command Lines

Creating temporary file "c:\Users\Tom\code\projects\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\Debug\RSP0000087603200.rsp" with contents
[
/Od /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc90.pdb" /W3 /c /ZI /TC .\main.c
]
Creating command line "cl.exe @c:\Users\Tom\code\projects\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\Debug\RSP0000087603200.rsp /nologo /errorReport:prompt"
Creating temporary file "c:\Users\Tom\code\projects\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\Debug\TMP0000097603200.tmp" with contents
[
1 /* CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID */ 24 /* RT_MANIFEST */ ".\Debug\triangle_wars.exe.embed.manifest"
]
Creating command line "rc.exe /fo".\Debug\triangle_wars.exe.embed.manifest.res" c:\Users\Tom\code\projects\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\Debug\TMP0000097603200.tmp"
Creating temporary file "c:\Users\Tom\code\projects\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\Debug\RSP00000A7603200.rsp" with contents
[
/OUT:"C:\Users\Tom\code\projects\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\Debug\triangle_wars.exe" /INCREMENTAL /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Debug\triangle_wars.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Users\Tom\code\projects\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\Debug\triangle_wars.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 freeglut.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

".\Debug\main.obj"

".\Debug\triangle_wars.exe.embed.manifest.res"
]
Creating command line "link.exe @c:\Users\Tom\code\projects\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\Debug\RSP00000A7603200.rsp /NOLOGO /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT"

Output Window

Compiling...
main.c
Compiling manifest to resources...
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.1.6723.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Linking...
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'freeglut.lib'

Results

Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\Tom\code\projects\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
triangle_wars - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
`

Comment: Just a thought, I'm not used to msvc tools: instead of a relative path ("./lib") try an absolute path ("c:\Users\Tom\code\projects\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\triangle_wars\Debug\Lib\").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By right clicking the project name in the Solution Explorer and selecting add->existing item, I was able to add freeglut.lib to the "namespace"  (improvised term) of the project... I think it should be able to take a path where libs reside, like I do under linux... Anyone who has more experience with this tool than me, I'd greatly appreciate a tip. Until then, at least I can keep writing code